# how to remove commas in an array in mongo db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

hie i am new to mongodb, iam trying to replace the commas, in my collection i have plenty of objects

### my collection is like below

```
{
 "name":"Mobile",
 "ProCategories":[
                  {
                   "title":"Home,-electronics"
                   }
                 ]
}
```

like above there are somany objects in my collection, now i want to remove the commas to all ProCategories array in all objects.

iam trying this using a js file in mongo shell like below

### my js file : update.js

```
db.companies.find().skip(0).limit(100).forEach(function (doc) {

  var replacedTitle = doc.ProCat.filter(function (catTitle) {
    return catTitle.title.replace(',', "");
  })

  db.companies.update({
    _id: doc._id
  }, {
    $set: {
      "ProCat": [{
        "title": replacedTitle
      }]
    }
  });

})
```

now in my mongo shell i am doing like this

```
load("url\\to\\my js file\\path")
```

i tried in different ways but it is not working
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var replacedTitles = doc.ProCat.map(function (catTitle) {
    return { title: catTitle.title.replace(/,/g, "") };
})
```

`filter` removes elements in an array that do not match a condition. This is not what you want to do. Instead, `map` applies a function to each element of the array, which is what you want to do. Additionally, you need to wrap each replaced string in an object since you want an array of objects, not an array of strings. The `/,/g` makes it so that every comma is removed, not just the first one. The rest should be modified like this.

```
db.companies.update({
    _id: doc._id
}, {
    $set: {
        "ProCat": replacedTitles,
    }
});
```

Comment: Your `replace()` will only replace the first `,` in each entry. The Question text implies that the OP wants all `,` removed. This is probably an issue left over from a disconnect between what the OP has described and what they coded.

Comment: @Makyen Right, nice catch.

Comment: thankyou @afuous solved my problem easily and also i learned how to use `map`